# How do I setup communication between a Silverlight Browser App and Embeded Web Browser Control

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, silverlight

I have a setup where I am hosting a Silverlight App inside of a webpage in IE8, IE11, and Chrome. Within our Silverlight App we would like to present some website content via the Web Browser Control. What are some methods we can use to communicate information back from the HTML / JS in the Web Browser Control back in the Silverlight Application.

For example:
We would like to reach out to a differenent intranet site to allow our employees to register certian options on the customer's order. When the employee clicks "Save" on that HTML form we would like to trigger some action in our Silverlight based on the data in the form.

Since it's all in house, we can make changes on the order intranet site to help us out.

Comment: Javascript Interop, [this](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/06/Silverlight-and-JavaScript-Interop-Basics) article explains it well.

Comment: @RobJ Post your comment as an answer, so I can give credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for info on the JavaScript interop, the MSDN documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076(v=vs.95).aspx).  This [article](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/06/Silverlight-and-JavaScript-Interop-Basics) gives a nice front to back overview.